# Ironpython subclassing .NET classes

Tags: .net, ironpython, subclassing

I am trying to subclass the .NET RoutedUICommand in IronPython.
I can do this as long as I do not pass any parameters to the **init** function. As soon as I do this, I get an ArgumentTypeException Instance() takes at most 5 arguments (2 given).
I've read that there is an .overloads dictionary but how do I use this on the **init** function? Here is my code:

```
class R(RoutedUICommand):
def __init__(self, win,*args, **kwargs):
    super(R, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.win = win

    self.keyGesture = KeyGesture(Key.X,ModifierKeys.Control)
    self.Exit = RoutedUICommand('E_xit','Exit',clr.GetClrType(RoutedUICommand),InputGestureCollection([self.keyGesture]))
    self.ebinding = CommandBinding(self.Exit,self.ExitExecute,self.ExitCanExecute)
    self.win.CommandBindings.Add(self.ebinding)

r = R(win)
```

RoutedUICommand has three overloads. How can I add my own paramters to my class using .overloads?

If I try to implement the **new** function:

```
def __new__(self,win):
    return super(R,self).__new__(self)
```

I am getting a MissingMemberException: object has no attribute 'ExitExecute'

Has anyone some ideas I could follow?

EDIT:

I found out how to do it:

```
def __new__(self,win,*args,**kwargs):
    return super(R,self).__new__(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

does the trick.

Comment: Lol, looks like I am getting the tumbleweed king.